# angular function not working in ie9

Tags: angularjs

My code is

```
function complileTemplate(dataum)
{
    angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile){
        var obj = $('#connectingFlights'); // get wrapper
        var scope = angular.element($("#top")).scope(); // get scope
        obj.html($(dataum));
        // compile!!!
        $compile(obj)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    });
}
```

[My error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huijf.png)

while getting scope value from top id it's throw **undefined**..

Thank you

Comment: The error shown in atached image is different from what you have mentioned.

Comment: it's shows undefined,while i was printing that scope variable ..

Comment: Does your element $('#top') exist in DOM when you call this?

Comment: Yes ..it's there!!.the same code working in >ie9 ,chrome,firefox